# Cannot access to localhost/xampp/index.php

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I just installed XAMPP for windows 7, control panel seems to work fine, I started MySql and Apache, the problem I have is, when I type localhost in my browser "Google Chrome" it sends me to "http://localhost/dashboard/"

when I change the url to "//localhost/xampp/index.php", it tells me:
"Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.11"

anyone can helps me out with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: where does your index.php reside?

Comment: Is there any `index.php` file in xampp directory ?

Comment: no, i really don't know where it is, I just watched a tutorial and he did this, but it's not working

Comment: some others told me to go here >> http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/index.php
but it's not working too

Comment: it can also be index.html :), not necessary that it will only have index.php file in the xampp root folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Create a page yourpage.html / yourpage.php whatever, you have to put all your pages in a folder in C:\Xampp\htdocs\ dir

Then try accessing following url:

> localhost/yourpage.html

or

> localhost/yourpage.php

That should work.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to tells me, however I don't want to make a website yet, i want to access the main page of the xampp, which i can add a password and stuff like that

Comment: Any solution? I deleted unintentionally the xampp index file and now I need to go there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be entering "http://localhost/index.php", because there is no such file in my ../htdocs/xampp/ folder called as index.php.

So may be the file you are referring to is in ../htdocs/index.php and to access it you need to hit the url as "http://localhost/index.php".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Xampp the default page will redirect you to /Dashboard Folder because it is sending the header `Location:http://localhost:80/Dashboard` to browser and browser understands that and redirects it.

The answer by @Sumeet Gavhale is correct. And instead of C://Xampp/htdocs folder xampp use to host contents inside /htdocs folder so if you want to find `C://Xampp/htdocs/index.php` type `localhost/index.php` (but that will redirect you to /htdocs/Dashboard folder).

If you want to change the hosting folder you should edit the Apache http/https configuration file (but that depends on your OS and file system).

> Note : The *Default Page* Word referred in second line of this
> answer means the document's name in the default documents in your
> Server (xampp in your case) (for eg: index.htm ,index.html , index.php etc). Will be loaded in your server and will be different in other's case (if they have done that) (index.php in first case (if not edited)).

## Index.php Of Xampp's Source Code

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
exit; ?>Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

But if you still want to view (execute) the page enter "//" in front of last and second last line.

Comment: It would be helpful to know why the index.php request is doing the redirect.  Is it the contents of the index.php file?  Or is it something at a higher level (like apache config) that is doing the redirect.

Comment: @JeffRichards Thank you for Improvement i Have Posted the Index.php file