# Searching for the proper xampp/htdocs/index.php code

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

First of all I went through the already asked question related xampp/htdocs/index.php. (eg.: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32064142/cannot-access-to-localhost-xampp-index-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004418/http-localhost-index-php-redirecting-to-http-localhost-xampp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055171/when-i-try-to-open-an-html-file-through-http-localhost-xampp-htdocs-index-htm) and may more other) But still cant reach the proper xampp/index.php file (or other way xampp/index.html). I would like to ask ( those who can reach the the following screen(s), which is displayed at 6:30 in this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5ghHLRv6uc) ).
Cause I can reach just the following schreen: which is displayed at 16:25 in this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw04VH9O5NQ).

the code what I see in my DEFAULT `index.php` is this:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>

Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

and I tried to modify this line: `header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');` to `header('Location: '.$uri.'/**xampp**/');`. (in the htdocs/xampp folder I tried to search for the page that is displayed in the tutorial that I linked first).

So ones again I want to reach somehow that screen that is displayed in the first tutorial, I went through all the folders in xampp folder but ther is no any that is redirecting to the proper searched site (most probably the newer versions does not consist this feature/ consist this features some other way).

Anyway I hope someone could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach the first screen you mentioned
[XAMPP Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jaeZ.png) & have installed xampp, then just enter in your browser: localhost/xampp

If you want it to come up whenever you type "localhost" in browser then change the index.php /dashboard/ to /xampp/ and it will show in browser if you only type "localhost" without any directory extension.

If you want to show a list of all your xampp/htdocs in your browser window instead of defining a single directory (i.e. like /dashboard) then just rename your index.php & index.htm files (or delete them) then when you type "localhost" or "http://localhost" you will be presented with all the index folders & files from your xampp/htdocs folder in your browser window.. select the local website folder and it will open the corresponding local index file...
Hope that is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer for my question. Probably it might be useful for the others that might face the same "problem". [HERE IS THE LINK TO THE RELIABLE SOURCE REGARDING IT.](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=74338&p=252257&hilit=index.php#p252257)

in short: there is no more /xampp/index.php, or as I mentioned "orange/yellow xampp page" (that I and some of us are searching for.), you have to find everything on the phpmyadmin!

Have a Nice day!!! ;)